# testcontainers ComposeContainer missing in Maven Central?

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, testcontainers

On Github I find ComposeContainer in https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/tree/main/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers, i.e. the containers subdirectory. When searching on Maven Central, (i.e. https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.18.3/versions) I find `testcontainers-1.18.3.jar`, but this archive does not contain `ComposeContainer.class`). Is this my fault?

Since I find `DockerComposeContainer` at the expected location I expect `ComposeContainer` there as well.

Comment: According to them it will be released in the next version 
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/5608

Comment: What confused me was the fact that it is already mentioned in the documentation.